# YouTube API v3 PHP get total number of views in a channel

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I would like to know how to get the total number of channel views. I've been searching all over the youtube API, but can't seem to find one.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [Channel.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) of the API. The total view of a channel is in the part `statistics`.

You need the channel name or the channel id. If you want the channel id but you only have the channel name, you can use this **[app](http://martialdidit.github.io/YoutubeID/)** to get the YouTube Id of the channel.

The result form is :

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"gMjDJfS6nsym0T-NKCXALC_u_rM/0FiX4yi2JggRgndNH8LVUqGkBEs\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"gMjDJfS6nsym0T-NKCXALC_u_rM/ch89JvwOeEbWio2fOHY7sxE7XCc\"",
   "id": "UCMGgBRBiijmpgL3xNuiDVOQ",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "5861117",
    "commentCount": "275",
    "subscriberCount": "40674",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "29"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The total view of the channel is in the part `[items"][0]["statistics"]["viewCount"]`

For this channel, the viewCount is : 5 861 117, the same number if you look at the channel https://www.youtube.com/user/Vecci87/about.

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=statistics&id=UCMGgBRBiijmpgL3xNuiDVOQ&_h=10&)**

**EDIT**

You can use [Youtube API Analytics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/). Important information, you need to be the owner of the YouTube Account, this method requires authenfification with Oauth2.
I made you a basic example, I define two date : today and a past day. I set the `metrics` to `view` and a `dimension` to `day`, to have the view for each days.
Finally i add all this values.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$datePast = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-".$period." day"));
try {
    $activitiesView = $youtube->reports->query('channel=='.$idde.'', $datePast , $today, 'views', array('dimensions' => 'day'));
} catch(Google_ServiceException $e) { }

$average = 0;
if(isset($activitiesView['rows'])) {
    foreach ($activitiesView['rows'] as $value) {
        $average += $value[1];
    }   
    $average = $average/count($activitiesView['rows']);
}
```

Full code example :

```
<?php

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeAnalyticsService.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

// Set your cached access token. Remember to replace $_SESSION with a
// real database or memcached.
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google+ PHP Starter Application');

$client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('REDIRECT_URI');
$client->setDeveloperKey('YOUR_DEV_KEY');

$youtube = new Google_YouTubeAnalyticsService($client);
$service = new Google_YouTubeService($client);
$auth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));  
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

    /***************USER STATS********************/
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $datePast = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-".$period." day"));
    try {
        $activitiesView = $youtube->reports->query('channel=='.$idde.'', $datePast , $today, 'views', array('dimensions' => 'day'));
    } catch(Google_ServiceException $e) { }

    $average = 0;
    if(isset($activitiesView['rows'])) {
        foreach ($activitiesView['rows'] as $value) {
            $average += $value[1];
        }   
        $average = $average/count($activitiesView['rows']);
    }


    /***************USER STATS********************/

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    //simple verification
    if(strpos($RedirectUri, "redirect_uri") !== false) {
        header('Location: error.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's a big help to me. Another follow up question..Is that possible to get a total view of channel on a specific date range?

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower nop, it's not possible, unless you use YouTube Analytics API but you need to be authenticated, and you need to be the owner of the channel.

Comment: Yes, Actually, that's ok, Can you give me some example please. Thanks :)

Comment: Code samples on how to get total channel views with a specific date range. You said it is possible unless we use YouTube Analytics API. :)

Comment: Beware that the Channel.list **viewCount** metric relates to the views of a _channel_, whereas the YouTube Analytics API's **views** are _video_ views : [views - core metric](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#views) : The number of times that a video was viewed. If you are retrieving information for a playlist, the metric indicates the number of times that a video was viewed in the context of a playlist. The YouTube Help Center provides additional information about how views are reported. This is a core metric and is subject to the Deprecation Policy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Following URL

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

2. Use the API Explorer to call this method on live data and see the API request and response
   [image: Sample Images]
3. Execute the API and see the response

[image]

4. View the Statistics Section there you can find the information what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

This link provides the youtube channel report in range. But when used with google php library it get hooked in a "User login required Error!"

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DMINE&start-date=2014-05-01&end-date=2014-06-30&metrics=views&dimensions=day&_h=3&

Is there any way i can access the channel analytics report in youtube V3 same as like in v3

http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=statistics&id=UCMGgBRBiijmpgL3xNuiDVOQ&_h=10&